# How to distribute data from GridDB to different data warehouses？

Tags: jdbc, data-warehouse, pdi, griddb

I am currently collecting data from different PLC devices to GridDB for storage. The format of the data is as follows:

| D_NAME | DATA | MSG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Siemens | 2021/10/4 | acbdfg |
| Omron | 2021/10/4 | ponged |

It is necessary to distribute the row whose device name is Siemens to Oralce,
and distribute the row whose device name is Omron to PostgreSQL,
**And realize the automatic execution of data distribution at regular intervals every day**

I'm currently trying to use PDI+windows schtasks,
Filter the data through the following SQL statements:

```
select * from t2021104 where D_NAME='Siemens'
```

At the same time, I also checked the availability of the database driver, all of which can be connected and used normally.
But unfortunately, I got the following error message:

```
2022/12/03 08:53:32 - OUT-Griddb.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [147001:JDBC_NOT_SUPPORTED] Currently not supported
2022/12/03 08:53:32 - OUT-Griddb.0 -    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLErrorUtils.errorNotSupportedFeature(SQLErrorUtils.java:241)
2022/12/03 08:53:32 - OUT-Griddb.0 -    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLErrorUtils.errorNotSupported(SQLErrorUtils.java:204)
2022/12/03 08:53:32 - OUT-Griddb.0 -    at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.internal.SQLPreparedStatement.setBigDecimal(SQLPreparedStatement.java:148)
2022/12/03 08:53:32 - OUT-Griddb.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.setPreparedStatementValue(ValueMetaBase.java:5472)
```

It seems that JDBC does not support the result, but I continued to check JDBC, and both the program and DBeaver can execute DDL and DML statements normally.
I tried to write the data in postgresq to GridDB and found that the execution was successful without any error message
I checked GridDB's log and didn't find any error log